# Get array length and push into each object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, foreach

I have a function

```
const output = {}
sites.forEach(obj=>{
    const ids = obj.ids
    if(ids && ids.length>0){
        ids.forEach(id=>{
            if(!output[id]){
                output[id] = []
            }
            output[id].push(obj.url);
        });
    }
});

fs.writeFileSync('cleanedData.json', JSON.stringify(output));
```

that takes data such as:

```
{ 
     url: "www.site.com", 
     ids: ["F20", "C10", "C05"] 
}, 
{ 
    url: "www.site.com/something", 
    ids: ["F20", "C05", "C10"] 
}, 
{ 
    url: "www.site.com/somethingelse", 
    ids: ["F20", "C12", "C05"] 
}
```

and transforms it so that I have a list of all ids and all urls with that id:

```
{
  "F20": [
    "www.site.com",
    "www.site.com/something",
    "www.site.com/somethingelse"
  ]
}, {
  "C10": [
    "www.site.com",
    "www.site.com/something"
  ]
}, {
  "C12": [
    "www.site.com/somethingelse"
  ]
}, {
  "C05": [
    "www.site.com",
    "www.site.com/something",
    "www.site.com/somethingelse"
  ]
}
```

I'm able to get a count of each id's array length with

```
console.log(Object.values(output).map(id => id.length))
```

But can't figure out how to include that as part of the forEach, so that I have a key/value in each object that shows the length of the array.

Comment: Where do you want this length in the result??

Comment: Why do you need the length as another key in the object, when you can just get the length of the array?

Comment: @Barmar - That resulting data is imported into excel, and would be helpful to display the length of each as there are a few hundred ids and it just becomes a list. If it could be a key/value pair within each id, so that each id has a length property and can be displayed next to each id when exported.

Comment: When I run your code I don't get the output you show. I get a single object, not an array of objects.

Comment: "*a key/value in each object*" - this doesn't make sense. Your `output` consists of only a single object.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `Object.values(output).map(id => id.length)`? Please show us the desired output data you want to get, otherwise it's not really clear what you are after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested objects in the output, and give it a `length` property that you increment when you push onto the array.

```js
const sites = [{
    url: "www.site.com",
    ids: ["F20", "C10", "C05"]
  },
  {
    url: "www.site.com/something",
    ids: ["F20", "C05", "C10"]
  },
  {
    url: "www.site.com/somethingelse",
    ids: ["F20", "C12", "C05"]
  }
];

const output = {};
sites.forEach(obj => {
  const ids = obj.ids
  if (ids && ids.length > 0) {
    ids.forEach(id => {
      if (!output[id]) {
        output[id] = {length: 0, urls: []}
      }
      output[id].urls.push(obj.url);
      output[id].length++;
    });
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: That's the nested structure I was trying to think of! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const sites = [{url: "www.site.com",ids: ["F20", "C10", "C05"]},{url: "www.site.com/something",ids: ["F20", "C05", "C10"]},{url: "www.site.com/somethingelse",ids: ["F20", "C12", "C05"]}]

const output = sites.reduce((a, { url, ids }) => {
  ids.forEach(id => {
    a[id] ??= { length: 0, urls: [] }
    a[id].length += 1
    a[id].urls.push(url)
  })
  return a
}, {})

console.log(output)
```